# Reading from the File

Tags: java

This program has 2 classes with a main method and is supposed to read from a file. My problem is that the line `double listPrice = fileScan.nextDouble();` gives an error exception like this `Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException`. The error is in this class:

Here is contents of the file:
Honda Accord

2004 16780.00 10.0

Chrysler SUV

2002 8600.00 0.0

Toyota Camry

2007 21799.99   3.0

Ford Escort

2006 12345.78   5.5

//note there is no space between each line

```
class Proj1P2CarAryListService 
{

  private ArrayList<Proj1CarData> carList = new ArrayList<Proj1CarData>();

  public Proj1P2CarAryListService()
  {
     carList = new ArrayList<Proj1CarData>();
  }

  public void readStoreCarsData()
  {


     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

     Scanner fileScan;
     boolean validName = false;
     double discountAmount;
     double netPrice;

     do 
     {

        System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
        String str1 = scan.nextLine();

        try 
        {

           fileScan = new Scanner(new File(str1));
           validName = true;


           while (fileScan.hasNext())

           {

              String name = fileScan.nextLine();
              String modelYear = fileScan.next();
              double listPrice = fileScan.nextDouble();
              double percentDiscount = fileScan.nextDouble();

              discountAmount = listPrice * percentDiscount/100.0;
              netPrice = listPrice - discountAmount;

              Proj1CarData proj1 = new Proj1CarData(name, modelYear, listPrice, percentDiscount, discountAmount, netPrice);
              carList.add(proj1);
              System.out.println(proj1.toString());

           }// end while

        }// end try

           catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
           {
              System.out.println("Invalid File name; enter again");
           }

     } while (!validName);


  }//readStoreCarsData
```

Comment: Please provide the contents of the file. Its almost certainly because the input in the file doesn't match what your trying to read in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type(Double must be separated by . **or , like said jlordo**), or that the token is out of range for the expected type. Perhaps it is a file content problem.

Comment: Well the file starts with String name of the car the next line has 3 different numbers like year, price, percent discount  2004 16000.00 10.0 and there is only one space in between so not sure why it gives exception. So it is 1 integer and 2 doubles

Comment: If you don't want to change the contents of the file read variable from file as a String and then parse it to Double:              double listPrice = Double.parseDouble(fileScan.next());
               double percentDiscount = Double.parseDouble(fileScan.next());

Answer (score 1):

The `nextDouble()` method of Scanner is locale-aware (see [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29)).
This means, if your locale is set to a country where '.' seperates a floating point number following would be a parsable double value: `123.456` while following number will give you a InputMismatchException `123,456`. In Europe `123,456`  would work, and `123.456` would throw an Exception. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider printing out each line. You might be getting more than you expect.

Comment: The code looks fine but that problem have no idea why it does that is it because i have incorrect toString method or something    String.format ("\t%-15s %-15s %-10.2f %-10.2f %-10.2f %-10.2f", name, modelYear, listPrice, percentDiscount, discountAmount, netPrice);